# dynamically fill listview android

Tags: android, listview

I want dynamically fill listview with List
It is my code:

```
ListView lis;
List<String> values=new  ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
    values.add("a1");
    values.add("a2");
    values.add("a3");
    values.add("a4");
    values.add("a5");
    values.add("a6");
    values.add("a7");
    values.add("a8");
    values.add("a9");
    values.add("a10");
    values.add("a11");
   lis =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 final    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values );
     lis.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     lis.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
        {  
               int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int count = view.getChildCount();

                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || (first + count > arrayAdapter.getCount()) ) {
                    fill_list();
                }
        }   

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
        { 



        }
    });  
    return rootView;
}

  public void fill_list() 
  {

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
        values.add("b "+ i);
      }
```

but it dosent work,my list is fill but Listview dosent fill.

Comment: does a1 to a11 is displayed? but not b+i?

Comment: yes,a1 to a11 displayed,but b+i dosent displayed

Comment: What if your list has less items than the screen's height? You will need to scroll the list (although it's not scrollable) for the items to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember to call `list.notifyDataSetChanged();` when you want to update listView content.

Also for this case I recommend you use a custom Adapter and implement your methods manually so you con override notifyDataSetChanged() method, maybe something like:

```
public class MyAdapter entends BaseAdapter{ 
    //Stuff...
    public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
        fillList();
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, sorry for my pseudocode.

Best regards.